# Grails with Birt params

Tags: grails, birt

Ok, the example from plugin birt helped me tons, but one question is bothering me, how can I pass params to the birt to select from id?

```
question | description
----------------------
1        | blabla
2        | xoxoxo
3        | tititi
4        | buhbuh
```

Example: I have this table above... From my grails application, I choose what question I want, so if I choose 1,3,4... The Birt report shows me selected only.

Basically, I have to change my dataset too, because my query is static and needed to be dynamic:.

```
...(query) and a1.question_id = 1 and a2.question_id = 2 and and a3.question_id = 3 (query)...
```

But in grails how I will pass the params to dataset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the Birt report receives the parameters with params, you can use this part of code

```
def options = birtReportService.getRenderOption(request, 'html')
def result=birtReportService.runAndRender(reportName, params, options)
render  result
```

. Remember don't forget place your rptdesing in a folder on (web-app)

Comment: And my query in `dataset` will know using, for example mysql: `@` as params?

Comment: look this video to use parameters in your dataset http://demo.actuate.com/demos/cascade/cascade.html

Comment: I got it yesterday. THanks!